# Cannot open database "Demo-Name" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So yeah, as I mentioned in the title I've got problem with Database.

I'm working on a project in which I'm using Entity Framework. I'm creating DB with the CodeFirst convention. After creating and adding some stuff to it, I want to check what is in there. I'm oppening MS SQL Server but there is no sign of my DB. (Why?)

So I'm attaching it and inspect if all was added/created in the way I wanted. But then when I want to do anything with my DB from VS this error occurs.

> Cannot open database "Demo-Name" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user ...

So what was done wrong by me? I'm also curious why it works without adding the string connection (of course before adding do MS SQL)

@EDIT
My connection string:

> `<add name="Demo1" connectionString="Data Source= (LocalDB);User=Jimmy;Password=none" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you show your connection string as well?

Comment: @loki  I changed the authentication in MS to Windows and SQL. and other things I mentioned in post. I also tried changing connection string to another and another...